# How do I select a value using the slide bar?

Tags: javascript, html

Can someone please help me with this project I am working on? I want to select either one of the two divs (KgDiv, LDiv) by clicking it, then use the slide bar to select a value between 0 and the maximum value of the Kilograms/ Liters paragraph, then use the Sell button to convert Kg or L to € at a rate of 1 to 1. Also the quantity (kg or l) selected using the slide var should be displayed next to the slide bar.

```js
var KilogramsV = 0;
var LitersV = 0;

function AddKg() {
  KilogramsV += 400;
  document.getElementById("Kilograms").innerHTML = KilogramsV + " " + "Kilograms";
}

function AddL() {
  LitersV += 340;
  document.getElementById("Liters").innerHTML = LitersV + " " + "Liters";
}
```

```html
<div id="KgDiv">
  <p id="Kilograms">Kilograms</p>
  <input type="button" onClick="AddKg()" value="+400Kg"></input>
</div>
<div id="LDiv">
  <p id="Liters">Liters</p>
  <input type="button" onClick="AddL()" value="+340L"></input>
</div>

<input type="button" onClick="Sell()" value="Sell"></input>
<p id="Money">€ 0</p>

<input id="SlideBar" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50"></input>
```

This is what I have so far.
Thanks!

I have watched yt videos but couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what [debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193) you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: A general note: input elements are self-closing. You don't need a closing tag, it should either be `<input/>`  or just `<input>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve your goal, we should be modifying your code and add some more JavaScript.

```js
var kilogramsV = 0;
var litersV = 0;
var selectedType = 'kg'; // Default selection

function addKg() {
  kilogramsV += 400;
  document.getElementById("Kilograms").innerHTML = kilogramsV + " Kilograms";
  if (selectedType === 'kg') {
    updateSliderMax(kilogramsV);
  }
}

function addL() {
  litersV += 340;
  document.getElementById("Liters").innerHTML = litersV + " Liters";
  if (selectedType === 'l') {
    updateSliderMax(litersV);
  }
}

function selectType(type) {
  selectedType = type;
  const selectionText = type === 'kg' ? 'Kilograms' : 'Liters';
  document.getElementById("ActiveSelection").innerHTML = `Active: ${selectionText}`;
  updateSliderMax(type === 'kg' ? kilogramsV : litersV);
}

function updateSliderMax(maxValue) {
  document.getElementById("SlideBar").max = maxValue;
  document.getElementById("SlideBar").value = 0; // Reset the slider value
  updateQuantity(0); // Reset the displayed quantity
}

function updateQuantity(value) {
  document.getElementById("SelectedQuantity").innerHTML = `Selected: ${value} ${selectedType.toUpperCase()}`;
}

function sell() {
  var quantity = document.getElementById("SlideBar").value;
  var money = parseInt(quantity); // Since 1 kg/l = 1 €
  document.getElementById("Money").innerHTML = '€ ' + money;
}
```

```html
<div id="KgDiv" onclick="selectType('kg')">
  <p id="Kilograms">Kilograms</p>
  <input type="button" onclick="addKg()" value="+400Kg">
</div>
<div id="LDiv" onclick="selectType('l')">
  <p id="Liters">Liters</p>
  <input type="button" onclick="addL()" value="+340L">
</div>

<p id="SelectedQuantity">Selected: 0 Kg</p>
<input type="button" onclick="sell()" value="Sell">
<p id="Money">€ 0</p>

<p id="ActiveSelection">Active: None</p> <!-- Indicates active selection -->

<input id="SlideBar" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" oninput="updateQuantity(this.value)">
```

### **What these codes do?**

- `selectType(type)` function sets which type of unit is active and prints it to the end user.
- `updateSliderMax(maxValue)` function updates the max value of the slider based on the selected type's total amount and resets the slider and selected quantity display.
- `updateQuantity(value)` function updates the text next to the slider to display the currently selected quantity along with the correct unit (Kg or L).
- `sell()` function converts the selected quantity into euros at a 1:1 rate and updates the "Money" paragraph to display the total amount in euros.

Answer (score 0):

All I added to your code was that it shows the value of the slider under the slider.

```js
var KilogramsV = 0;
var LitersV = 0;
var sliderValue = 0;
function AddKg() {
  KilogramsV += 400;
  document.getElementById("Kilograms").innerHTML = KilogramsV + " " + "Kilograms";
}

function AddL() {
  LitersV += 340;
  document.getElementById("Liters").innerHTML = LitersV + " " + "Liters";
}
function sliderChange(val) {
    document.getElementById('slider').innerHTML = val;
    sliderValue = val;
}
```

```html
<div id="KgDiv">
  <p id="Kilograms">Kilograms</p>
  <input type="button" onClick="AddKg()" value="+400Kg"></input>
</div>
<div id="LDiv">
  <p id="Liters">Liters</p>
  <input type="button" onClick="AddL()" value="+340L"></input>
</div>

<input type="button" onClick="Sell()" value="Sell"></input>
<p id="Money">€ 0</p>

<input id="SlideBar" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" oninput="sliderChange(this.value)"></input>
<p id="slider"> 50 </p>
```